# Angular Variable not change after update from response data

Tags: angular

Value of variable is not updated on server response.

In interview.component.ts

```
export class InterviewModeComponent implements OnInit {
interViewAwaits: Interview[] = [];
awaitLoading: boolean = true;

constructor(private translate: TranslateService,
            private interviewModeService: InterviewModeService) {
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getAwaitInterviews();
}

getAwaitInterviews() {
    this.interviewModeService.getInterviews(1).subscribe(
        res => {
            console.log(res);
            this.interViewAwaits = res.data;
            this.awaitLoading = false;
        }, error => {
            console.log(error);
        }
    )
}
```

In inverview.component.html

```
<div class="kt-widget4" *ngIf="awaitLoading == true">
    <div class="kt-widget4__item">
        <div class="kt-spinner kt-spinner--sm kt-spinner--brand"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="kt-widget4" *ngIf="awaitLoading == false">
    <div class="kt-widget4__item" *ngFor="let item of interViewAwaits">
         <div>{{item.first_name}}</div>
    </div>
</div>
<button (click)="getAwaitInterviews">Get</button>
```

In console log, I can see data response from server but the variable `awaitLoading` never change to false after I set it to false, but if I click button to call function `getAwaiInterviews()` again, it works.
What happen here? I don't know what to do.I sorry for my bad English. I'm native.

Comment: Are you sure the console logs the correct response and not an error?
Where do you use the `awaitLoading` variable?

Comment: What is your `console.log` value? If an error you will have always `awaitLoading = true`.

Comment: Try to use methods ngAfterViewInit or ngAfterContentInit

Comment: I console.log in first function is success response function. I'm sure got response data from api like in postman, not error.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a Stackblitz for your example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-x2unw7) and the value of `awailtLoading` is getting set to `false` there.

Also, a little correction in your code:

```
<button (click)="getAwaitInterviews()">Get</button>
```

Comment: I want getAwaitInterview() on loading ngOnInit when view render and Button is testing to function.